# unable to locate web element from drop down

Tags: jquery, selenium-webdriver

i am not sure how to identify my xpath from the below>>

```
<td onclick="hrefClick(this,4,0);" 
    onmouseout="menuLevel2MouseOut(this);" 
    onmouseover="menuLevel2MouseOver(this);" 
    style="padding-left:30px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:3px; cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;" 
    class="">
      Drop Boxes
</td>
```

This from a drop down where the all the list are having the same id.

Can it be done using jquery?

Comment: Can you perhaps show the actual dropdown so we can see better what you're trying to do?

Comment: The id element is supposed to be unique to the page, this probably isn't causing your issue, but you might want to change your current use of id to a class.

Comment: i am trying to select an option from a drop-down. There are five dropdowns. All of them have the same id. so it makes difficult to select the particular option-- this is the actual problem.

Comment: The HTML i attached earlier is for the option i want to select

Comment: please ask in case any more details required

Comment: To Explain my actual problem in detail, there are 5 drop downs in my app and i want to select an option from one of the drop down. But all the five drop downs are being identified with same id 
that makes difficult to select the required oneand go further to select the option. Hope you guys can help

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done with using jquery. **Use eq() Selector** and then click on the element you want in dropdown.

Comment: This is not an actual drop down. Its a onmouseover functionality like when i keep the mouse over that, it displays the menu list. will it work for that too?